# How do I make a number of looping scripts execute at startup?

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I have a few Python scripts, all of them involving `while True`: and a wait timer so they run at varying intervals. They do things like monitor a serial port and look for new versions of my code on a remote server. I haven't used cron because some require offsets (e.g run at ten seconds past the minute) and I wanted to keep things very simple.

Using `rc.local`, I run `hook.py` on startup. What can I put in `hook.py` to run `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py` simultaneously and continuously? I tried `subprocess` (with `shell = True`) but I'm not sure the next line / next subprocess command will execute until the first one finishes - which will never happen. Plus it has some weird behaviour I'm struggling to debug (I can rw files using their absolute paths if I run the script directly; when subprocess runs them, it can't find the files).

Any suggestions? Just want something simple that can simultaneously execute several new python scripts. Platform is a Raspberry Pi.

Alternatively: if there's code I can put in `rc.local` that will spawn a new python process for all .py files in a specified directory, that would work too.

Comment: this sounds a lot like active waiting, so be sure you have a look at [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep).

wrt. your question, can't you just append a `&` to the end of your `rc.local` lines? In normal bash syntax that would run the task in background, so if your scripts never terminate, that should to the trick, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it would be better suited for spawning via cron instead of an infinite while loops.

But if you want to continue running them in rc.local just put the & at the end of your command:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/you/command.py &
```

This runs the command in the background.

If you want to run all Python files in a given directory I would write a bash script like:

```
for file in /home/you/*.py
do
    if [ "$?" == "0" ]
    then
        /usr/bin/python "$file" &
    fi
done
```

We will need more information about your path issues to tell you more.